# how to make html5 game run on mobile device browser with phaser?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari, phaser-framework

I have just found a html5 game framework named [phaser](https://phaser.io/) and it says that this framework support both PC browser and mobile device browser only if they support Html5. So I wrote a sample as the tutorial and It worked fine in my PC with Chrome, But When I launch it with chrome browser on my iphone. It just give a blank page with nothing.

Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Phaser - Making your first game, part 1</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/phaser.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });

var score = 0;
var scoreText;
function preload() {
    game.load.image('sky', 'assets/sky.png');
    game.load.image('ground', 'assets/platform.png');
    game.load.image('star', 'assets/star.png');
    game.load.spritesheet('dude','assets/dude.png', 32,48);
    game.add.sprite(0,0,'star');
}
var platforms;

function create() {
    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
    game.add.sprite(0,0,'sky');
    platforms = game.add.group();
    platforms.enableBody = true;
    var ground= platforms.create(0,game.world.height-64,'ground');
    ground.scale.setTo(2,2);
    ground.body.immovable=true;
    var ledge = platforms.create(400,400,'ground');
    ledge.body.immovable=true;
    ledge = platforms.create(-150,250,'ground');
    ledge.body.immovable = true;
    player = game.add.sprite(32,game.world.height-150,'dude');
    game.physics.arcade.enable(player);
    player.body.bounce.y = 0.2;
    player.body.gravity.y = 300;
    player.body.collideWorldBounds = true;

    player.animations.add('left',[0,1,2,3],10,true);
    player.animations.add('right',[5,6,7,8],10,true);
    cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
    stars = game.add.group();
    stars.enableBody = true;
    for(var i=0;i<12;i++){
        var star = stars.create(i*70,0,'star');
        star.body.gravity.y = 100;
        star.body.bounce.y=0.7 + Math.random()*0.2;
    }
    scoreText = game.add.text(16,16, 'score:0',{fontSize:'32px',fill:'#000'});

}
function collectStar(player, star){
    star.kill();
    score = score + 10;
    scoreText.text = 'Score: ' + score;
}
function update() {
    game.physics.arcade.collide(player, platforms);
    game.physics.arcade.collide(stars,platforms);
    game.physics.arcade.overlap(player,stars,collectStar, null,this);
    player.body.velocity.x=0;
    if(cursors.left.isDown){
        player.body.velocity.x=-150;
        player.animations.play('left');
    }
    else if(cursors.right.isDown){
        player.body.velocity.x=150;
        player.animations.play('right');
    }else {
        player.animations.stop();
        player.frame=4;

    }
    if(cursors.up.isDown && player.body.touching.down){
        player.body.velocity.y = -350;
    }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And you can try the code here: http://game.ximing.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience, the supported renderers are for some reason not always properly recognized when using auto detection. Try using

```
Phaser.CANVAS
```

in the game constructor.

Comment: it worked! thank you, but according to the specification, AUTO should better choice. Never thought this could case a problem.

Comment: Glad to help, especially on something I've also been struggling with :)

Comment: Thank you very much! One of my sprites was rendering as a black rectangle. Changing the line of code from Phaser.AUTO to Phaser.CANVAS fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I use the CocoonJS launcher app on my iPhone to test out my games.  I'm not familiar with Android, but for iOS users, just connect your iPhone to your computer, open up the applications folder, and then drag and drop a copy of your game into the CocoonJS app, then sync your phone.  You can then test your game on you phone as if it were in a wrapper (no URL, or any signs of it being a web application).